# Renomear tag «expressjs» para «express.js» ou «express» e adicionar sinônimos

Tags: debate, suporte, tags, tags-sinônimas

É uma sugestão apenas

- Renomear a tag [expressjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expressjs) para [express.js](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express.js) ou para [express](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express)

Dependendo de qual seja a tag principal, sugiro que todas estas se refiram ao mesmo assunto:

- [express](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express)
- [expressjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/expressjs)
- [express.js](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express.js)

Assim seriam todas sinônimos, notem que no SOen usam https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express, sem `js` ou `.js` e no site http://expressjs.com apesar do domínio ter JS eles se referem somente como Express, mas é opcional, eu pessoalmente gostei de `express.js`, mas fica a critério da comunidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo, feito. Mantive [express](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express) e deixei as outras como sinônimo.

Comment: Veja como ficou o wiki e a descrição da tag https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/express/info ;)

Comment: Caprichou, hein? :)

Comment: Tava meio que pronto, só tive que ajustar alguns textos :)